# I want to force the user to edit the value of the NumericStepper by using the arrows only so they cannot type a value directly into the value field

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark, numericstepper

When using the NumericStepper I want to force the user to only be able to edit the value using the NumericStepper's up and down arrows. I do not want the user to be able to type in a value directly. How can i do this in flex 4? Can someone please provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo need to set the NumericStepper's textDisplay as non editable. You can do it once the component has been initialized:

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function init():void {
                nmStppr.textDisplay.editable = false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:NumericStepper id="nmStppr"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
            creationComplete="init();"/>
```

or creating a custom skin as explained [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/06/12/creating-a-non-editable-spark-numericstepper-control-in-flex-4/)

Comment: +1.  I especially like the idea of creating a custom skin here.  Since it is only one property change, I like it because you don't have to build an entire skin... you can just derive from NumericStepperSkin like in the article that @javierfp linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can try another way so that you can not change the value in NumericStepper. These value would become non-editable.

```
<s:NumericStepper id="num"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
            creationComplete="init();"/>

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function init():void {
               num.mx_internal::inputField.editable=false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```